# Integrating a toggle into a class with JQuery

Tags: jquery

This is probably a very basic question and has been answered before on this site but everything I've looked at so far is different than what my needs are or I just don't understand at the level I need to in order to solve this.

I am filtering a list of months and that functionality is working fine, but I would now like to show the user which month they clicked on and have it stay active until they click a different month; so a toggle I guess.

Here is the code I have:

```
  $("a.filter").on("click", function(e) {
    var a = $(this);
    $("#view .hide").hide();
    $("#view div." + a.data("filter")).show();
  });

  <a href="#" class="filter" data-filter="February">February</a>
  <a href="#" class="filter" data-filter="March">March</a>
```

How do I target the correct anchor the user clicked on and add my active class to that anchor?

EDIT:
I was able to get this working but had to use `find`. I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it but here is what I have now:

```
$("a[data-filter='" + a.data("filter") +"']").addClass('element-active');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `siblings` to choose anchors which user doesn't click.

```css
a.active {color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="filter" data-filter="February">February</a>
<a href="#" class="filter" data-filter="March">March</a>
<script>
  $("a.filter").on("click", function() {
    var a = $(this);
    a.siblings().removeClass('active')
    a.addClass('active')
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Shuo, I just got it working but I used `find` to add the class. Let me post above and you can tell me if your code will do the same thing, I like your code better, it looks much cleaner than mine does

Comment: I just tried your code and yes, it does add the class to the clicked anchor, but if I click off the active anchor onto another one, the new one highlights with the active class but the anchor clicked off of keeps the class. There should only be 1 anchor with an active class at a time

Comment: Strange, it is only one active a time like snippet above.

Comment: I can see it clearly works in your example but I can't the old row to remove the class. I have to do this in order for it to work: `$("a.filter").removeClass('element-active');`

Comment: I agree, it is strange. It's not a big deal though. It's working and that's all I care about right now. Thanks! I'll accept the answer

Comment: Oh, that's because you use `a[data-filter=month]` to select element, there is only one element was selected, it has no siblings. So you have to use `a.filter` instead.

Comment: Okay cool. So I'm doing it right then. I like using siblings better so I don't have use `find`. That was the biggie for me anyway. Thanks so much for the help!!